# Regular expression to replace this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
"ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb2 | value | tb10 | value"
```

What can I do with regex to replace, for example `'| tb2 | value '` with `''` with this,

```
"ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb10 | value"
```

I know the value `tbxx` is a variable that I have.

The Regex engine is javascript, not .Net or C#.

Comment: What regex engine? .NET? Java? Javascript? PERL?

Comment: Do you really need a RegEx here? A pure string replace would be much simpler.

Comment: If you know the exact sub-string beforehand, a simple replace(...) will be easier: no need for regex.

Comment: This sounds like a great place to use awk (if available).

Comment: regex engine --> javascript. I just know 'tbxx', i want to remove the value that is associative to tb1 and i dont know the exact size of the value i just know that is between | tbxx | and | tbxx2

Answer (score 3):

The exact syntax depends on the language you are using, but you need to escape the `|` character since it has special meaning inside regular expressions.

In perl you would do something like:

```
my $string = "ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb2 | value | tb10 | value";
$string =~ s/\| tb2 \| value //;
```

In java it would be:

```
String string = "ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb2 | value | tb10 | value";
string = string.replaceAll("\\| tb2 \\| value ", "");
```

Comment: ok... but my problem is that value is not "value", can have letters and numbers

Answer (score 0):

**javascript** replace

```
var 
    deletePair = 'tb2',
    strIn = "ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb2 | toDeletevalue | tb10 | value",
    pattern = new RegExp("\\| " + deletePair + " \\| ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ", "g"),
    result = strIn.replace(pattern, '');

document.write(result === "ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb10 | value" 
    ? 'ok'
    : 'failed'
);
document.write('<br />' + result);
```

**edit**

Added `deletePair` in which you specify what **key** in your `key | val` representation you want to delete

Comment: ok... but my problem is that value is not "value", can have letters and numbers

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information for a generic solution[1]. Is your string guaranteed to be regular?

It sounds like your data is well formed - you should parse it in some way:

**Python:**

```
import csv
input = "ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb2 | value | tb10 | value"
parts = input.split("|")
r = csv.reader([input],delimiter='|')
parts = r.next()
try:
  i = parts.index(" tb2 ")
  parts = parts[0:i] + parts[i+2:]
except ValueError:
  pass

print "|".join(parts)
```

prints:

```
ABC-2341241244 | tb1 | value | tb10 | value
```

[1] Is your delimiter `'|'`? Or is it `' | '`? Can you escape `|` in your data? Are you only searching on `tbXX` identifiers?

Comment: my delimiter is ' | '. i want to do what u just did

Comment: How do i do that in javascript?